# BinaryJS Server Response

Tags: node.js, stream

Given the example bellow:

```
binaryServer = BinaryServer({port: 9001});

binaryServer.on('connection', function(client) {
  console.log("new connection");


  client.on('stream', function(stream, meta) {
    console.log('new stream');
    strean.on('data', function('data'){
    //(code to store audio in buffers)});

    stream.on('end', function() {
      //end of stream
      //(routine that calls an addon and convert speech to text)
      //****Immediate response to client******
    });
  });
});
```

Now, my objective is to send immediately a response (to client) when its generated. I am trying to do this with [BinaryJS](http://binaryjs.com/) but I cant understand how.

Comment: Perhaps [this](https://github.com/binaryjs/binaryjs/blob/master/examples/imageshare/server.js) would give you some idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Server side:

```
binaryServer = BinaryServer({port: 9001});

binaryServer.on('connection', function(client) {
  console.log("new connection");


  client.on('stream', function(stream, meta) {
    console.log('new stream');
    strean.on('data', function('data'){
    //(code to store audio in buffers)});

    stream.on('end', function() {
      //end of stream
      //(routine that calls an addon and convert speech to text)
      //****Immediate response to client******
      stream.write(some_variable);<---just do this
    });
  });
});
```

Client Side:

```
client.on('open', function() {

    Stream = client.createStream("some meta information);
    //(some rotines)
    Stream.on('data', function(data){ ///-->recebe resposta do stream.write()
          console.log("RESULTADO: "+data);
    });
}
```

);